# Looking for Soviet Union or Russia transportation GIS dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation, historical, russia

I am looking for a dataset that can I obtain about Russia's transportation.
I am working on a PDF of the former Soviet Union's St. Petersburg map that I have here and need to georeference it. Is there a way that can I go to a website where there is an English version? The map I have is written in Russian.

Comment: Why do you mention St. Petersburg but ask for entire Russia?

Comment: @Jan Doggen because sometimes they don't always provide one local so they might include the rest of the country..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this: [Russian gis on SE's gis site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50180/russian-gis-data)